# Pandas remove column by index

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], columns=['a','b','b'])
>>> df
   a  b  b
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

And I want to remove second `'b'` column. If I just use `del` statement, it'll delete both `'b'` columns:

```
>>> del df['b']
>>> df
   a
0  1
1  4
2  7
```

I can select column by index with `.iloc[]` and reassign DataFrame, but how can I delete only second `'b'` column, for example by index?

Comment: That's interesting. Reassigning sounds the appropriate move. Thinking twice, you know you want to delete 2nd `b` not based of the column names as you have duplicates but indeed on an index. Thus your algorithm somehow uses that index. So why just not change the columns to an index based in that case?

Comment: @Boud good suggestion, actually I could rename all columns which I want to delete and then delete by name, will try when will get to home

Comment: afaik, `del df['b']` translates to block manager command to remove relative items from all blocks, i.e. roughly equals to reassignment `df = df.iloc[:,:2]`

Answer (score 6):

```
df = df.drop(['b'], axis=1).join(df['b'].ix[:, 0:1])

>>> df
   a  b
0  1  2
1  4  5
2  7  8
```

Or just for this case

```
df = df.ix[:, 0:2]
```

But I think it has other better ways.

Comment: This is the best way of retaining the first instance of a duplicate column that I have yet found!